# IF ELSE or CASE in MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

This is my MySQL Statement :

```
select
tableG.id,
TestName,
test_group.Merged as TestGroupMerged,
TestSuiteName,
test_suite.Merged as TestSuiteMerged,
test_case.Deleted as TestCaseDeleted,
Long_image_name as Image, 
from 
test_table

-- new added line -- inner join Long_image_name on test_B.long_image_id = image_table.long_image_id
    inner join Long_image_name on test_A.long_image_id = image_table.long_image_id


where
    db_test_id = ?
```

We are adding the image to another table(test_B) if test_B doesn't contain the image it should look in test_A if test_A also doesn't have it then blank image(nothing).

I am thinking to solve it like this:

```
IF (test_B.long_image_id IS NULL) THEN 
inner join Long_image_name on test_A.long_image_id = image_table.long_image_id
ELSE
inner join Long_image_name on test_B.long_image_id = image_table.long_image_id
```

I cannot test the implementation yet because the database  doesn't have any image files currently. Would using ´CASE´ be a better idea?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can't make conditional joins like that, but you could do the IF() test at a higher level:

```
SELECT COALESCE(test_B.long_image_id, test_A.long_image_id)
FROM ...
INNER JOIN ... test_A ...
INNER JOIN ... test_B ...
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are testing for NULL and joining on IDs im assuming the image would only be in 1 of the 2 tables, which means the two INNER JOIN in the answer by Marc B should be changed to LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT COALESCE(test_B.long_image_id, test_A.long_image_id)
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN ... test_A ...
LEFT JOIN ... test_B ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Or....

You *should* be able to do the following:

```
 select *
 from test_table test
 inner join Long_image_name image on 
      (test.long_image_id IS NULL and test_A.long_image_id = image.long_image_id) or 
      (test.long_image_id IS NOT NULL and test_B.long_image_id = image.long_image_id)
```

Haven't fully tested it on my end, but it's worth a shot.

Side note, your joins don't look quite right, from my quick glance.  Make sure you're joining between both tables right, either by alias or actual table name.  You'll have to fix the references in the suggested join based on the same concept.

**Side note:**  I've answered this from the mindset of SQL Server 2000, but should still point you the right way.